# Links working but redirecting to "Not Found" page?

Tags: html, weebly

This is hard to explain so bear with me...

A little background story to help you understand my problem...

I use Weebly under Netfirms to edit my website. There are certain things you can't do in the website editor so I have to go into the HTML code to edit in order to do it (e.g - linking something on a page to a part further done on the same page or linking something on one page to another page at a certain point on the page)

I have done it in the past and every time I make small changes to my website through the website editor (e.g - editing text, adding new pictures, etc) it overwrites the changes I made to the HTML code so I just have to paste the old HTML code back in and they work again.. But I recently made some big changes on my website which include adding a bunch of new pages and stuff so I added in the old links to the new HTML code since adding new pages so I can't just copy and paste the old HTML...

This is my current problem:

The links work, but they don't at the same time. Everything is correct (spelling and correct pages) and when you click on the links, they redirect to a blank page that says "Not Found".. I don't understand.. I've gone over all my spelling and everything matches up and should work but it doesn't... Please help! HTML links for "Low Temp Installation" and "Heat Distortion" on the "Installation Instructions" page are below..

```
<div class="paragraph">Please view <em><u><a href=”/installation-
instructions.html#low_temp_installation”>Section 5.1 - Installation in Low 
Temperatures</a></u></em> in the installation instructions for help on 
installing our panels in low temperatures.<br /><br /><strong>We are not 
responsible for distorted panels due to excessive heat.</strong><br />Please 
view <em><u><a href=”/installation-
instructions.html#heat_distortion”>Section 5.2 - Heat Distortion</a></u>
</em> in the installation instructions for help installing and operating 
heaters and furnaces in areas using our PVC panels.<br /><br /><span 
style="color:rgb(42, 42, 42)">Delcan Products Ltd. obligation covered under 
the 15 year warranty is limited to the replacement of defective products 
only. &#8203;Warranty for defective products shall not include the cost or 
expense of any labor necessary for the replacement of the defective 
materials.</span><br /><br /><font size="5">Please <u><a 
href="/contact.html">contact us</a></u> if you have any questions about your 
project.</font></div>
```

HTML labels "Low Temp Installation" and "Heat Distortion" on the "Installation Instructions" page are below..

```
<h2 class="wsite-content-title" h2 id=”low_temp_installation”><font 
size="5">SPECIAL INSTRUCTIONS</font></h2>

<div class="paragraph">If possible, avoid installation of panels when below 
10&deg;C (50&deg;F). Allow panels to acclimate to room temperature for at 
least 24 hours prior to installation.<ul><li>When installing in temperatures 
below 8&deg;C (48&deg;F), insert a dime between panels.</li><li>When 
installing in temperatures below 0&deg;C (32&deg;F), insert a nickel between 
panels. This will allow space for panel expansion in hot weather.</li></ul>
<div id=”heat_distortion”> Delcan Products Ltd. is not responsible for 
expansion problems. The <a href="/warranty.html">warranty</a> on this 
product is void if not installed according to these instructions.</div>
```

Comment: Note the incorrect quotes being used in `”`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used bad quotes around the attribute values. It should be

```
<a href="/installation-instructions.html#low_temp_installation">
```

instead of

```
<a href=”/installation-instructions.html#low_temp_installation”>
```

Comment: how do I change the quotes to look like that??

Comment: @Kaylee: eh? Open your page in text editor and edit replace bad quotes with good ones? Or in database the same operation, if you store data there.

Comment: thank you!! I will try that and hopefully it will work :)